# how to perform a set of task before the process gets killed using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

**How to handle signal from external file in java script file.**
*i have a shell script which stops all the running process. when my node process is getting stopped or killed i want to perform some task and then allow this node to stop/kill.*

**i have a java script file in which i want to write this handler.**

> How can i catch this stop signal and perform some task before getting
>   killed

i have tried:

```
function method1(){

logger.info("this is our method to be executed before getting killed");
}
process.on('SIGTERM',method1());
```

Comment: `process.on('SIGTERM', func1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can register handle on exit

```
process.stdin.resume();
function exitHandler(options, err) {
    //exit logic
}
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind());
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind());
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind());
```

Comment: what is the use of process.stdin.resume(); here. also i tried the above example too and it is not working